# Returning 1 result from multiples in the DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to query my DB and return only one name for each.  (php/MySQL)

Example data in table:
Mary
Tim
Mary
Rick
Tim
Mary
Rick

I would like to know how to only grab each name once and display them.  Instead of looping through and grabbing and displaying all of the names multiple times.

Thanks in advance!
Frank

Answer (score 4):

That's what the DISTINCT operator does:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`name`) from `users`;
```

Comment: Heh you beat me by 10 seconds :D Have a +1, and a good day Sir!

Comment: Perfect.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
```